# How would you translate "redactar" into English?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

The dictionaries I've checked all translate it as "to write" but my Mexican girlfriend assures me that this fails to capture the whole meaning. What's the closest word or phrase in English?

Comment: ["to draw up"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=redactar)?

Comment: I would also suggest "to write" or "to write **up**", if that makes any difference. What about [**redact**](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=redact)? You could also use "compose", "edit" and a plethora of synonyms, but the key is why does you Mexican girlfriend say that it does not capture the whole meaning. Which aspects are missing? You could also ask her what would she suggest.

Comment: @Diego I don't know about enGB and elsewhere, but in enUS, to *redact* is almost exclusively used to mean *to delete*, so I'd highly recommend against using *to redact*.  *Compose* or *write up* work well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about `to draft` or sometimes `to compose`? It seems what I've gathered from definitions [such as these](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/redactar) is that it is a formal verb that covers all the actions involved in the professional composition of documents.

Answer (score 1):

Redactar comes from the ver `to write` in Spanish but is a word that joins the idea of writing something that has passed as: "Luis redacta todas las cartas en el periódico".

So I will still use *write* as part of your sentence and I will probably add up some words that it will intensify the meaning of it as:

> Luis is the one in charge of **writing and editing** all the letters at the newspaper

As Diego suggested, *compose* and *edit* can help out to develop the meaning of your sentence.